# excel to html SheetJS

Tags: html, jquery, excel, html-table, sheetjs

I'm trying to convert a excel file (which user upload it in a input file tag) to a html table tag.
I found a code on "redstapler" but it doesn't work.

I don't know where is the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script lang="javascript" src="xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar"><span>Red Stapler - SheetJS </span></div>
<div id="wrapper">
        
        <input type="file" id="input-excel" />
</div>
<script>
        $('#input-excel').change(function(e){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                        var wb = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array'});
                        var htmlstr = XLSX.write(wb,{sheet:"sheet no1", type:'binary',bookType:'html'});
                        $('#wrapper')[0].innerHTML += htmlstr;
                }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me...

I downloaded and embedded the **xlsx.mini.js** from https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs
Make sure your path is correct here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/xlsx.mini.js"></script>
```

And also check the name of your sheet which you want to read.

```
sheet:"sheet no1"
```